Contextual filter "Content ID from URL" doesn't work in page preview
Some of my pages have a banner image, which is rendered from a view block. The view has a contextual filter "Content ID from URL". This loads an image based on the value of the media that is referenced by the main_image_media field. This works fine from the average user's perspective.
My issue is that the contextual filter doesn't work in preview mode, as the URL is a uuid like "/node/preview/3daf8e85-aff3-4dfd-a312-a9ac48aabc48/full" with no reference to the node id or alias for the page, so the banner image doesn't show up in preview. How can I render the image on the preview page?
This is such a minor issue, but they should be able to see the page exactly as it is going to look before they publish it.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2978024
